# Can I buy American AppleCare+ and use it in Europe?

Tags: applecare

I recently bought an Apple Watch Series 2 in Germany. I now want to buy AppleCare+. When I go to [**this site**](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/) and get to the "Purchase" page, United States is chosen by default and the price is $50. If I switch to Deutschland, the price becomes 65€, which is considerably more expensive for some reason.

Will there be any issue if I go with the US AppleCare+?

Comment: It is advisable to contact Apple Support in order to get this question answered. If they reply to your request and the answer is yes (which i don't know for sure), you'll have an official printable statement with timestamp and date!

Comment: Apple's warranty is a _global_ warranty, as is AppleCare coverage. So, if you purchase a device in the US and then six months later move to Germany, your device is still covered. The same goes with AppleCare. However, each country has different consumer laws, and this will affect the ToS etc. In your case, you've purchased a product in Germany and then want to get AppleCare+ from the US. I'm not convinced you'll be able to complete the purchase, but if you can you will be covered, it just may take a little longer to establish your coverage. So make sure you have your receipts etc.

Comment: I recently helped a lady who purchased a new iPhone from a _local_ online store. About 10 months later the iPhone developed a fault, and while it was definitely under warranty, it took a while to establish this fact because the serial number came up as having been purchased in Thailand, and because it was dated about 7 weeks earlier. She needed to show her purchase receipt to _correct_ the commencement date for her warranty, as it was originally showing as only 8 days remaining compared to the two months she thought she had.

Comment: It did get all sorted, and she purchased AppleCare afterwards to extend her coverage, but the issue had to get escalated before it was resolved. Only you can decide whether any extra stress you may have in the event of a problem, is worth the lower cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where can I purchase the AppleCare Protection Plan?**

> Depending on the Apple product, the AppleCare Protection Plan is available at the Apple Online Store, Apple Retail Stores, and many Apple Authorized Resellers including many wireless service providers. Apple recommends that you purchase the AppleCare Protection Plan in your country of residence, because each AppleCare Protection Plan has terms and conditions specific to consumers in the country or region in which the plan is offered. Please see the AppleCare Protection Plan Terms and Conditions for complete details.

source: https://www.apple.com/asia/support/products/faqs.html

So Apple provides different protections based on your region of the world and the applicable ToS.

**I was asked to clarify**

Apple's ToS for AppleCare is country-specific based upon where its purchased. So if you purchase a US plan, the language includes only language about certain laws in US states where they diverge from the general contract. Same goes for the EU - if you buy an EU plan certain countries have variations on the laws.

That said, from briefly perusing AppleCare ToS, all of them seem to offer the ability to take your device to "an Apple Retail Store" to have it repaired under warranty and no further qualification is given. If you've purchased a warranty outside of your own country I'd presume that that means you can get it repaired anywhere Apple has a store.

I am not an Apple rep nor does this answer have any weight on what Apple actually might do. I'm guessing your intention with this question is to save a few bucks on your AppleCare. In that case, I'd ask if it's worth about the ~15 euros difference in price to protect what is likely a >1000 Euro device?

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? As it stands, it doesn't give me enough useful information. What are the concrete consequences of purchasing AppleCare+ in the US, as opposed to Germany?

Comment: Clarified. . . .

Comment: It's a 450 Euro device. And 15 bucks is 15 bucks ;-)